# How can I implement a global high score ladder?

Tags: java, leaderboards, android

Are there any existing frameworks I can build on?  Should I build my own?  How can I prevent fake scores from being posted to it?

Comment: What platforms are you talking about?  Does it have to work across platforms?

Comment: @Dennis specifically using Java and developing for Android.

Answer (score 6):

ScoreLoop is available for Android platform.

You can use [ScoreNinja](http://code.google.com/p/scoreninja/) too. ScoreNinja offers an easy way to implement global scores but requires to view your score in the ScoreNinja application.

Otherwise Cocos iphone provides a global score with [CocosLive](http://www.cocoslive.net/). You can use CocosLive.net or use your own GoogleApp Engine VM. CocosLive is not available on Android platform but the protocol is REST with JSON and can easily be ported.

My current solution is CocosLive for Android and iPhone with my own VM but i will use ScoreLoop in my next game for social network integration.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure there is one framework that spans multiple platforms but there are platform specific frameworks for sure. Two that come to mind for the iPhone are [Scoreloop](http://www.scoreloop.com/) and [OpenFeint](http://www.openfeint.com/developers).

Comment: OpenFeint has been announced for Android -- see http://www.openfeint.com/developers/android .

Answer (score 2):

Check out **OpenFeint** : [Getting Started With OpenFeint SDK for Android 1.8](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/getting-started-with-openfeint-sdk-for-android-1-8/)
Easy to start !

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

(1) User gets a score in the game.

(2) Create the string "Username,score,timestamp" or something similar.

(3) Append a salt (secret string) to this string: "username,score,timestamp,SALTSTRING"

(4) Calculate a hash of this string with your favourite algorithm, (MD5, SHA...).

(5) Post "Username,score,timestamp" together with the hash you computed to your site:
www.yoursite.com?str=username,score,timestamp&hash=MYHASH
or something similar

(6) On your server, redo the calculation, i.e. create  "username,score,timestamp,SALTSTRING" and then compare with the hash the user submitted.
If no match, then something has been tampered with.

Note, if the user can obtain the class files, then they can be decompiled, and thus the salt can be seen. However, if the user can decompile your program, there is no way to prevent false high scores: the user may modify the code to make the game easier and use that version. You will have no way to check for that.